# Menu links not working in IE

Tags: routes

When I click on certain links in menu in IE a page with error message "Internet Explorer cannot display this page" appears. Other browsers are OK.

Problem is with these two links
"http://localhost/?q=calendar"
"http://localhost/?q=user/login"

Do you know what is wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give any meaningful answer you need to describe your problem better. I did notice that your urls seem to lack your site name

`http://localhost/?q=calendar` vs `http://localhost/drupal?q=calendar`

This can happen if you don't create the urls with the l/url function regardless of browser being used.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I tested IE in virtual machine so I couldn't use localhost and those links were "hardwired" in the menu. Is there some variable I can use that will create the right link?